# how to change a variable name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this code in C# but it can go up to 1000 pages .  how can I have the name of the variable be page_i  without having to have a case and write out 1000 cases ?

```
    int i=0;
    while (i< sizeofallpages){
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:

                PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
                break;
            case 1:

                PdfPage page1 = document.AddPage();
                break;
            case 2:

                PdfPage page2 = document.AddPage();
                break;
    }
```

Comment: Can you use an array or other container to hold all your pages, and then just access them by their index?

Comment: The variable name is irrelevant once compiled, also your pages are disposed of outside of the case statement

Comment: Did you actually type this out to 1,000?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't avoid this.  This is why programming is so hard and we get paid so well.  Also, writing code like this makes it nearly impossible for others to work on something you wrote, thereby ensuring your job is secure.  Win, win, win.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Will You may want to add a "sarcasm" tag to your brilliant comment. Otherwise, someone unfamiliar with the industry may take it seriously :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Quiet, you!  You're going to ruin it for all of us!

Comment: @Anon - Don't forget `default:`

Answer (score 6):

If you like to keep references to the pages:

```
int i=0;
PdfPage page = null;
PdfPage[] pages = new PdfPage[sizeofallpages];
while (i < sizeofallpages)
{
    page = document.AddPage();
    pages[i] = page;
    i++;
}
```

After that, if you would like to use a page, simply access it by:

```
page[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create a List of objects and then use it accordingly.

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

for(int count=0; i<sizeofallpages; count++){
    list.add(new MyObject());
}
```

Then, just access the objects from the List.

Comment: @Jim just out of curiosity, any particular reason why did you edit the ArrayList to List<MyObject>? Thanks

Comment: Because what you originally had wouldn't compile. I figured you meant `List<MyObject>`.

Comment: ArrayList has been obsolete since the introduction of generics in C# 2.0.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks Jim. I am a Java developer, and figured that List would solve the OP's question so I answered in Java terms. ArrayList is still used in Java. But thanks for the info, thats just some more knowledge for me.